# Riak leveldb Corruption

Tags: riak, leveldb

I'm having the following error :

```
@riak_kv_vnode:maybe_create_hashtrees:178 riak_kv/456719261665907161938651510223838443642478919680: unable to start index_hashtree: {error,{{bad match,{error,{db_open,"Corruption: truncated record at end of file"}}}
```

Full log here : http://pastebin.com/Lgaqw2Wu

Running Version :
Riak :
riak_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb

OS  :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Tried vnode repair , partition repair , node restart and i traced the code to a function that initialises the LevelDB , its clear there is a corruption on our hashtree.

Hoping some can give a tip.

Regards

Comment: Is this a programming question, or would it be better served one of the sister sites like http://serverfault.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashtrees are used for anti-entropy exchanges.  If you have a corrupt file in your hashtree it is probably for the best to simply delete the files for that tree and allow them to rebuild.

There should be an `anti_entropy` directory in your data directory that contains these files, if you delete the files and restart Riak, it should be able to rebuild those from scratch.

Comment: This is correct you can stop the node , drop the contents of anti_entropy and start the node. It will rebuild the data by itself.
Thanks @Joe